# Can my JavaScript regex handle dots within quotes?

Tags: javascript, regex, string, replace, regex-lookarounds

I have created a regular expression to add `?.` to JavaScript expressions within a string.

For example: `bar.foo.some` becomes `bar?.foo?.some`.

It works perfectly, except when there are dots between quotes (`'` or `"`).
I mean, when I test the regex on this expression: `data.foo ? 'yes. I can do it': 'no.'`, it becomes `data?.foo ? 'yes?. I can do it': 'no?.'`.

What I need from this regex is to ignore the dots inside the quotes. However, I am unsure how to instruct the regex to do so.

The regex I created is quite complex as it covers cases such as `?.[` and `)?`. for index access, as well as function calls `(some[...] and some.fn().bar)`.

Below are some possible expressions with the expected output as comments:

```js
[
  `bla.params.query ? 'yes.' : 'no.'`, // expected output: bla?.params?.query ? 'yes.': 'no.'
  `bla[foo]`, // expected output: bla?.[foo]
  `bla[foo].bar }}`, // expected output: bla?.[foo]?.bar
  `bar.some().bar`, // expected output: bla?.some()?.bar
  `bla`, // expected output: bla
  `bla.some`, // expected output: bla?.some
  `bla.some.go`, // expected output: bla?.some?.go
  `bla ? 'bla.some': 'you.go'`, // expected output: bla ? 'bla.some': 'you.go'
  `bla.`, // invalid expresssion, should ignore because there nothing after the dot. expected output: bla.
].forEach((v) => {
  v = v.replace(
    /(?<=[a-z_])\.(?!\?)|(?<=[\]a-z_])(?=\[)|(?<=[\]a-z_])(?=^\()|(?<=]|\))(?=\[)|(?<=]|\))\./gi,
    '?.'
  );

  console.log(v);
});
```

Comment: At some point, it'll become easier to use a proper parser and operate with macros on the AST. Regular expressions cannot parse JavaScript, you will always have false matches with them.

Comment: I agree with you. However, the only case I'm currently missing is the one I've been focusing on with this regex. It has been a significant part of my learning process, and I really wish to understand how to solve it and address this particular problem.

Comment: The last one can be mitigated by `\.(?!\?|$)` instead of `\.(?!\?)`.

Comment: @JonSud Basically you'll have to check with lookbehind from the start of the program or lookahead until the end of the program that the part you're matching is outside of a string, i.e. surrounded only by non-strings and complete strings. This is quite inefficient, and quite complicated as you have to consider escaping rules - even if you do not have to parse the entirety of js expressions, there is considerable complexity in which lexical tokens can or cannot contain quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to explicitly express which kind of character one wants to allow/match **before** each to be replaced property accessor, either dot or (opening) bracket, one might choose the notation of [unicode escapes](https://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html).

A [character set/range](https://javascript.info/regexp-character-sets-and-ranges), which allows letters, numbers, underscore, closing bracket and closing parentheses, embedded into a  [positive lookbehind](https://javascript.info/regexp-lookahead-lookbehind#lookahead) then would look like this ...

```js
(?<=[\p{L}\p{N}_\])])
```

And only dots which in addition are **followed** ([positive lookahead](https://javascript.info/regexp-lookahead-lookbehind#lookbehind)) by either letters, numbers and underscore might be considered valid replacement points (matches), ...

```js
\.(?=[\p{L}\p{N}_])
```

... whereas such an additional rule would not apply to an opening bracket.

Thus, assembling all of the above with the [alternation](https://javascript.info/regexp-alternation) of either an opening bracket or a dot which has a followers rule, one already comes up with ...

```js
(?<=[\p{L}\p{N}_\])])(?:\[|\.(?=[\p{L}\p{N}_]))
```

And in order to prevent matches enclosed into single quotes, one could add another lookbehind, this time, a negative one like ...

```js
(?<!'.*?)
```

The final regex ... [`/(?<!'.*?)(?<=[\p{L}\p{N}_\])])(?:\[|\.(?=[\p{L}\p{N}_]))/gu`](https://regex101.com/r/fmfcwR/1) ... fulfills the OP's requirements as far as it covers the OP's provided use cases. It does not mean, it's the ultimate solution. The OP could refine the pattern to the OP's needs.

**A bullet proof solution anyhow had to be built on a parser/lexer.**

```js
const regXDotBracketAccessors =
  // see ... [https://regex101.com/r/fmfcwR/1]
  /(?<!'.*?)(?<=[\p{L}\p{N}_\])])(?:\[|\.(?=[\p{L}\p{N}_]))/gu;

console.log([                           // expected:

  `bla.params.query ? 'yes.' : 'no.'`,  // bla?.params?.query ? 'yes.' : 'no.'
  `bla[foo]`,                           // bla?.[foo]
  `{{ bla[foo].bar }}`,                 // {{ bla?.[foo]?.bar }}
  `bar.some().bar`,                     // bar?.some()?.bar
  `bla`,                                // bla
  `bla.some`,                           // bla?.some
  `bla.some.go`,                        // bla?.some?.go
  `bla ? 'bla.some' : 'you.go'`,        // bla ? 'bla.some' : 'you.go'
  `bla.`,                               // bla.

  ].map(item =>
    item.replace(
      regXDotBracketAccessors,
      match => `?.${ match !== '.' && match || '' }`
    )
  )
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

To skip `.` inside single or double quotes, you can use a negative lookahead to ensure that the `.` is not followed by a closing quote. Here's the updated regex:

```
/(?<=[a-z_])\.(?!\?)(?=(?:[^'"]|'[^']*'|"[^"]*")*$)|(?<=[\]a-z_])(?=\[)|(?<=[\]a-z_])(?=^\()|(?<=]|\))(?=\[)|(?<=]|\))\./gi
```

This regex is similar to the previous one, but it adds a lookahead assertion to check that the `.` is not followed by a closing quote. The lookahead matches any number of characters that are not a quote or a quote that is not followed by another quote. This ensures that the `.` is not inside a quoted string.

```js
[
  `bla.params.query ? 'yes.' : 'no.'`, // expected output: bla?.params?.query ? 'yes.': 'no.'
  `bla[foo]`, // expected output: bla?.[foo]
  `bla[foo].bar }}`, // expected output: bla?.[foo]?.bar
  `bar.some().bar`, // expected output: bla?.some()?.bar
  `bla`, // expected output: bla
  `bla.some`, // expected output: bla?.some
  `bla.some.go`, // expected output: bla?.some?.go
  `bla ? 'bla.some': 'you.go'`, // expected output: bla ? 'bla.some': 'you.go'
  `bla.`, // invalid expresssion, should ignore because there nothing after the dot. expected output: bla.
].forEach((v) => {
  v = v.replace(
    /(?<=[a-z_])\.(?!\?)(?=(?:[^'"]|'[^']*'|"[^"]*")*$)|(?<=[\]a-z_])(?=\[)|(?<=[\]a-z_])(?=^\()|(?<=]|\))(?=\[)|(?<=]|\))\./gi,
    '?.'
  );

  console.log(v);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that is that it fails to distinguish between dots inside strings and dots used as property access operators in JavaScript objects.

RegExp is designed for linear pattern matching, in your case it needs to ignore something with double quotes or single quotes and it is not RegExp's forte.

A solution could be to break the string into pieces and apply regex to non string parts like this:

```js
function safeRegexReplace(str, regex, replacement) {
    var parts = str.split(/(".*?"|'.*?')/); // or \.(?!\?|$)

    // for loop for the parts without quotes
    for (var i = 0; i < parts.length; i++) {
        if (i % 2 === 0) { // If the index is even, we are not inside a string
            parts[i] = parts[i].replace(regex, replacement);
        }
    }

    // Join all
    return parts.join('');
}

[
  `bla.params.query ? 'yes.' : 'no.'`, // expected output: bla?.params?.query ? 'yes.': 'no.'
  `bla[foo]`, // expected output: bla?.[foo]
  `bla[foo].bar }}`, // expected output: bla?.[foo]?.bar
  `bar.some().bar`, // expected output: bla?.some()?.bar
  `bla`, // expected output: bla
  `bla.some`, // expected output: bla?.some
  `bla.some.go`, // expected output: bla?.some?.go
  `bla ? 'bla.some': 'you.go'`, // expected output: bla ? 'bla.some': 'you.go'
  `bla.`, // invalid expresssion, should ignore because there nothing after the dot. expected output: bla.
].forEach((v) => {
  v = safeRegexReplace(v, /(?<=[a-z_])\.(?!\?)|(?<=[\]a-z_])(?=\[)|(?<=[\]a-z_])(?=^\()|(?<=]|\))(?=\[)|(?<=]|\))\./gi, '?.'); //every little combination
  console.log(v);
});
```

I'm assuming that the string does not contain nested strings.